# How to serialize to a file with Microsoft Bond

Tags: c#, bond

The Input and output streams [section](http://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#input-and-output-streams) of the Microsoft Bond documentation provides this sample code to deserialize from a file:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("example.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    var input = new InputStream(stream);
    var reader = new CompactBinaryReader<InputStream>(input);
    var example = Deserialize<Example>.From(reader);
}
```

I tried the reverse to serialize to file, but nothing is written to the file.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("example.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    var output = new OutputStream(stream);
    var writer = new CompactBinaryWriter<OutputStream>(output);  
    Serialize.To(writer, example);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the OutputStream hasn't been flushed into the FileStream. Try adding an explicit call to `OutputStream.Flush` like the [stream example](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/939c298ff6d619dbc0bc9f5ca25c2088de86d83b/examples/cs/core/stream/program.cs#L25) does:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("example.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    var output = new OutputStream(stream);
    var writer = new CompactBinaryWriter<OutputStream>(output);  
    Serialize.To(writer, example);
    output.Flush();
}
```

I was not around when `OutputStream` was designed, so I cannot comment on the decision process that resulted in it not implementing `IDisposable`.